# Looking for conversation transcripts

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for conversation transcripts. These can be from real sources such as radio or TV interviews, or even phone and IM captures, or fictional conversations such as plays and movies.

I don't need the actual audio/video, I am only looking for transcripts at this time. Personally identifying information is unnecessary, aliases or even `[SPEAKER 1]` would be fine.

I would prefer to avoid mixed narratives like "This American Life".

YouTube could be a good source for interviews that have closed-captioning.  In which case I just need the list of videos.

Thanks

Comment: Can movie and tv series sub be ok for you?

Comment: Yes - pretty much anything that has dialog in text format.

Comment: I should clarify a little bit. Closed Captions are fine, but it needs to identify a speaker so that I can follow the context.  This become really messy if no speaker is identified and the dialog is more than 2 people.  I didn't realize how fragmented movie dialog was till I tried to read the CC without the visual clues - lesson learned!

Comment: The other piece I should clarify - I am really looking for a database of transcripts.  One-offs are nice, but a data source is really ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Open.edu is another good source for conversation transcripts of interviews, although you'll have ascertain them as I do not see a download button:
http://www.open.edu/openlearn/history-the-arts/culture/english-language/example-interview-transcripts

Comment: Thank you @albert.  I was able to see the example-interview which was perfect!  However it was the only one.  It was more an example of "how to perform an interview" Vs. a database of transcripts.

Answer (score 1):

There is GECO at Stuttgart University (http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/forschung/ressourcen/korpora/IMS-GECO.html)

It is not exactly open data, but available free of charge for academic research. Consult the cited website on how to get access to GECO.

Comment: Is the content in English?  The source looks to be German.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChronoFish Yes, it contains English and German dialogues. For details see the metadata record here: https://vlo.clarin.eu/record;jsessionid=818D4AFB096E8025EF58C43CE71ED80B?0&q=geco&docId=http://hdl.handle.net/11858/00-247C-0000-0023-512E-7

Comment: Thanks @jknappen.  I contacted them and they informed me that all the conversation was in German.  So close..... :)

Answer (score 1):

I know Italians subs, but there is a lot in English also.

For example: http://www.english-subtitles.pro

I don't know if this is really ok for laws.

Comment: Thanks... The data doesn't identify the character who is speaking (by alias or otherwise) so there is no way that I can "follow" the dialog.  As you mentioned I'm not sure the legality of it either...so it's not exactly "open" data :)